# Hardcode android app category in APK itself

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, android-manifest

I read at many places that it is possible to hardcode in APK itself, the category in which your app will appear after installation. For eg- Firefox app is hardcoded to appear in the 'Internet' category.

I want my testing app (not yet released on play store) itself to appear in a certain category.

> How can I do it in APK itself?

Thanks in advance :)